# Imprimir de una consulta sql el count(*) en php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo esta consulta preparada en un fichero php.

```
$consulta = $conn->prepare("SELECT examen.idexamen,examen.detalles, count(*)
        from examen,preguntas
        having count(*) IN
        (SELECT count(*) FROM preguntas
        group by preguntas.examen)");
```

Y quiero imprimir también el count(*) y he probado con esto:

```
    while($f1 = $consulta->fetch()){
            echo $f1[3];
        }
```

y no funciona.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu consulta hay 3 campos, estás intentando obtener el elemento de un índice inexistente en la respuesta de tu consulta. Recuerda que la primera posición del array de la respuesta siempre empezará en 0, por lo que:

`$f1[0]` Será `examen.idexamen`

`$f1[1]` Será `examen.detalles`

`$f1[2]` Será `count(*)`

Te recomiendo que cuando tengas algún problema con PHP pruebes a mirar el log de errores que se genera en el servidor ya que siempre te va a decir donde se encuentra el error así como alguna pista del mismo.

Comment: me funciono gracias